# How to send data(server_respond) to a specific port number in http.server on localhost in python?

Tags: python

Suppose there is a  server built using http.server module in python. And several clients requested data to the server. But i want to make the server respond only to some specific clients(ports).
Actually i want to distinguish clients with port number(assume all clients are on localhost).

So  how can i achieve this .please help

thanks

Comment: Can you show us some code you tried.

Comment: `messagetosend={"apple":1,"orange":1}
  self.wfile.write(json.dumps(messagetosend).encode())`

Comment: actually i have no idea how to do it, that's why  i am asking

Comment: Just create a request handler : see http.serverBaseHTTPResuestHandler. You can then check the user address port in  handler input variable.